# Getting undefined error for method defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, interactjs

I have been trying to implement drag and drop functionality for buttons in my angular application using InteractJS

I wanted to call a method defined in class from drop event of interactable div, but getting following error.

[image: core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'methods' of undefined]

My current code:

HTML

```
<div class="example-box drag-drop plugins">
        Image
</div>


<div class="dropzone">
  <h3 style="color:white;">Dropzone</h3>
</div>
```

TS

```
interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
      overlap: 0.75,
      accept: '.plugins',

      ondrop: this.onDrop,
    })

    interact('.drag-drop')
      .draggable({
        inertia: false,
        autoScroll: true
      })
  }


  methods() {
    console.log("Inside methods()");
  }

  onDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.methods();
  }
```

I have trimmed down the code to make more readable. I was guessing that maybe when event is fired angular is not in control, so **this** is actually undefined.

Comment: in `this.methods();` this does not have a method `methods()`

Comment: Hi aRvi, methods() is defined inside class and both interact() methods are defined inside ngOnInit(), looks like I over trimmed the code. I will update the code soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the meaning of `this` keyword to the `onDrop()` event handler. Without it, the statement `this.methods()` is actually referring to `methods()` function inside the event handler. Try the following

```js
interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
  overlap: 0.75,
  accept: '.plugins',

  ondrop: this.onDrop.bind(this),          // <-- use `bind()` here
})
```